# C++ String Element Finding

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I was solving the question :
write a function that takes in a string and prints first non repeating character.  In other words I need to find first character which appears only once in entire string.
I understand solutions are already available, however below is what I coded:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>


using namespace std;


void main()
{
    string S1;
    int NonRepeatElement,StringLenght,temp;
    unordered_map <char, int> ElementMap;
    unordered_map<char,int>::iterator it;
    char KeyValue;

    cout<<"Please enter your string"<<endl;

    cin>>S1;

    StringLenght=S1.length();

    NonRepeatElement=0;

    for(int i=0;i<StringLenght;i++)
        {
            if(ElementMap.find(S1[i]) == ElementMap.end())
                ElementMap[S1[i]]=1;
            else
                ElementMap.find(S1[i])->second++;
        }

    for(it=ElementMap.begin();it!=ElementMap.end();++it)
    {
        if(it->second==1)
        { KeyValue=it->first;
          break;
        }
    }


   for(int i=0;i<StringLenght;i++)
   {
       if(S1[i]==KeyValue)
       {
           cout<<"First Non Repeating character is "<<S1[i]<<endl;
           break;
       }
   }

}
```

Now I do get element which appers only once but its not first real element but its first sorted element.
E.g. if input string is zaaabbcccdjjj
then ouptput is d not z
can anyone suggest why even unordered_map is behaving like this ?

Comment: By first non-repeating character, do you mean a character that is not *adjacent* to a same-char value? I.e. "abcac" has *no* "repeating" characters if the definition is looking for some "cc" rather than "cac". Either are solvable, but the solutions will be radically different, so clarify your question (you appear to be trying to account for the latter rather than the former). I would expect the vernacular in that case to be "find the first *unique* character".

Comment: Yes You are right. I edited my question. It is actually "find the first unique character".

Comment: Ok. then the answer is don't enumerate the map via iteration after building it. Enumerate the *string* again, searching for the first entry via the map `find` method that has a count of `1`. I'll post it if you need an answer below (and probably should anyway).

Comment: Ohh Great. That works fine , however can you please explain why iterating over map gives wrong results? What feature about MAP gave this wrong behavior?

Comment: The map is unordered to *anything* (well not entirely true, its a hash-map but thats beside the point, and it looks like the hash of `d` is lower than the hash of `z`). Enumerating it will give you the hash-table ordering with collisions Even using an ordered map would still not work, as it would simply sort on-char. The position in the *string* is what you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be enumerating the *map*. You should be enumerating the *string* once the map is built.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    unordered_map <char, int> ElementMap;
    std::string S1;

    cout<<"Please enter your string"<<endl;
    if (cin >> S1)
    {
        for (std::string::iterator it = S1.begin(); it != S1.end(); ++it)
            ++ElementMap[*it];

        for (std::string::iterator it = S1.begin(); it != S1.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (ElementMap[*it] == 1)
            {
                std::cout << "First non-repeating character is " << *it << '\n';
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Alternative: The Lookup Table**

Another way of doing this if the domain of the input data is fixed and **small** (and in this case it is) is using a simple lookup table. The `char` data type has at-most `(1 << CHAR_BIT)` elements, and the values themselves can be used as immediate indexes to the table. Thus you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter your string: ";

    std::string s;
    if (std::cin >> s)
    {
        unsigned int elems[ 1 << CHAR_BIT ]={};
        for (auto ch : s)
            ++elems[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)];

        for (auto ch : s)
        {
            if (elems[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)] == 1)
            {
                std::cout << "First non-repeating character is " << ch << '\n';
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

The benefit is O(1) complexity for each element lookup, both on the initial "map" population and on the repeat enumeration for finding the first `1`.  Total complexity is O(2N), i.e. O(N) where N is the string length. For finding unique chars in a large input stream, this would significantly out-perform a hash or order-based dynamic map.

But there is a cost: Don't try this with a 32bit `char` type; a 4gB automatic array is no place to call home.

Comment: Ohh Great. That works fine , however can you please explain why iterating over map gives wrong results? What feature about MAP gave this wrong behavior? And also why we always do ++it and not it++ for iterators ?

Comment: The first I explained in general comment. The second (`++it`) is an efficiency habit, just knowing how it++ generates a temp copy, increments the iterator, then returns the temp. In this case the compiler optimization would likely throw out all the temp-stuff, but I always do it with prefix-inc if I have no use for the "before" value (and in this case, I don't).

Answer (score 0):

This looks over complicated. All you have to do is checking element[i] and element[i+1]. As long as they are equal you increment a count. When they are different you check the count. If the count has not been incremented, you have a non-repeating element.

In pseudo-code:

```
* set count = 0
* for i = 0 to n-1
    if element[i] == element [i+1] then count++
    else
       if count == 0 then print element[i] and break
       else count = 0 (and continue)
```

Comment: I am solving problem which would produce output:(1) if input = aaaabbbbcccdddejjj output e , 2) if input abbcdddj output = a . Basically I need to find first element which appears only once in string. Sorry  for miswording the problem statement.

Comment: Yes, I got it all right. You still don't need a map. I see no reason for that.

Comment: What would be efficient way to do this ?